# how to call a unit test project by a windows application?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-extent-report

I am new to selenium and C sharp i somehow managed to write a code that does the unit testing of my application and creates a Extent Report with all my 7 test cases output Everything is working as expected The issue is i do not want every time to log into visual studio and run the selected test case Is there any way i can create a Windows application and make the test cases run with a click of a button

I have a total of 7 test cases and runs perfectly when running i select them all and run the selected tests, but i need not want to go there everytime , instead want to run it from some windows application.

Comment: There already is a great Windows application that you can run that allows you to run your tests with a click of a button. Its called Visual Studio. I dont understand what you're trying to achieve here. Do you just want something more lightweight?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your tests in unit tests project, you can create a windows console app and add your test project as dependency to it.

Then you can create your test class objects in main function and call test methods.

```
using Test.Project.Namespace;

    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                TestClass testclass = new TestClass();
                testclass.TestMethod1();
                testclass.TestMethod2();
                etc...
            }
```

It can be improved in many ways but you got the idea.

Comment: Mark it as valid answer then please

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a Windows batch file that triggers your automation. Since you are using NUnit, this should be pretty straightforward. You point it at your automation dlls, you can specify test categories, etc. Take a look at [the docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line) and other resources on the web.