# Run selenium test case from a console application c#

Tags: c#, selenium

console app with a batch file which will hit my Automation testing application and runs selected test cases. I have test case with code coverage and it runs from my visual studio . and now on top of it I have to create a console app which will keep some time interval and hit my VS test case and execute it.Any links will be helpful.

I expect the test case pass and fails status

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015236/how-to-call-a-unit-test-project-by-a-windows-application/58024148#58024148

Comment: Please post which testing framework you will be using? (MS Test, NUnit, XUnit, etc). Otherwise this question is too board.

Comment: Sorry , Am using NUnit for my test check.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the batch file I use to run my Selenium tests with multiple runsettings files.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST Results MKDIR Results
SETLOCAL
SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform"
SET VSTEST=vstest.console.exe
SET TESTS=.\bin\Debug\something.something.Tests.dll

IF "%~1"=="" (
    FOR %%J IN (*.runsettings) DO CALL :func %%J
) ELSE (
    CALL :func "%~1"
)

GOTO :EOF

:func
ECHO.
ECHO %~1 **********
ECHO.
"%VSTEST%" %TESTS% /Settings:"%~1" /Logger:trx /ResultsDirectory:Results
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use NUNit's console runner to run tests from the command line, or on a build server. I've had great success with running my tests this way.

First, you need to install the `NUnit.ConsoleRunner` Nuget package onto your project.

Then, navigate to the NUnit.ConsoleRunner directory under your `packages` folder that exists in the project directory.

Open `NUnit.ConsoleRunner > tools` folder to get into the same directory as the .exe itself.

Then, you can run:

`nunit3-console {Path to your project's .dll} --testlist={Path to .txt testlist}`

With valid parameters, it looks something like this:

`nunit3-console C:\Users\christine.harbour\Repository\AutomationTestSuite\AutomationTestSuite.dll --testlist=C:\Users\christine.harbour\Repository\AutomationTestSuite\MyTestList.txt`

Your testlist should contain namespaces of the test cases you wish to run, separated by a line break. For example:

```
AutomationTestSuite.Tests.MyTestClass_1.MyTest
AutomationTestSuite.Tests.MyTestClass_2.MyOtherTest
```

After you run the tests, the results will be saved in the `NUnit.ConsoleRunner > tools` directory. The results are in XML format and can be programatically parsed to push your test results to another tool.

There are plenty of arguments you can pass into the ConsoleRunner, including build configuration and framework version, all which are specified on NUnit's documentation.

NUnit console runner also integrates with Cake, which is a build scripting tool for C# projects. So, you could hypothetically clean / build your project, restore missing package references, and run your tests, all from the console.

More info on NUnit console runner can be found here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line